# Spring Data JPA: How to get the data from a nested 1-to-1 relationship?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm relatively `new` to spring data `jpa` but i've been working with `orm` in the `typescript` world (typeorm/mikrorm). I have a simple `1-to-1` `uni-directional` relationship between a `Book` and a `Picture`.

My Book entinty

```java
public class Book implements Serializable {
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="picture_id", nullable = false)
    private Picture picture;
}
```

The picture entity

```java
public class Picture implements Serializable {
    ....
    @Id
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String url;
}
```

So I've created my services and I'm able to persist the data into the database. For the database i'm using `mysql` which is running on my local machine.

In my controllers, On the `GetMapping` i want to get the book with it's picture for example when i hit the server at `http//:127.0.0.1/api/v1/books/book/1` I want to get the following as response:

> Postman

```json
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "book1",
    "picture":{
        "id": 1,
        "url": "url1" 
    }
}
```

Instead I'm getting the following response:

```json
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "book1"
}
```

Here is what I've tried in the `BookController.java` and it seems not working, at some point I'm not getting the `picture` object for the book.

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping(path = "/api/v1/books")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class BookController {
    private final BookService bookService;
    private final PictureService pictureService;
....

    @GetMapping("/book/{bookId}")
    public ResponseEntity<Book> getBook(@PathVariable("bookId") Long bookId){
        return ResponseEntity.status(200).body(this.bookService.getBook(bookId));
    }

}
```

Comment: What about if you debug your application, have you inspected if `book.getPicture()` is `null`? Could you be "lazy loading" the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that is because you told Jackson to ignore that property. Just remove the @JsonIgnore annotation

Comment: If i dont put the `@JsonIgnore` I'm getting a nested infinity response on the PostMapping during the creation of the `Book`

Comment: That was the thing that i was missing thank you it worked fine now, you are my new hero

Comment: Yep, in case of a bidirectional association you should ignore one side in order to avoid that error while serialising.